How Istio mTLS works with Prometheus
I am trying to make prometheus work with istio with mesh wide Strict mTLS enabled. From the istio documentation, istio certs has been shared with prometheus container and update scrapping job to use those certs.
In the same TLS setting section here, "The control plane, gateway, and Envoy sidecar metrics will all be scraped over cleartext. However, the application metrics will follow whatever Istio authentication policy has been configured for the workload."
How will application metrics follow authentication policy/mTLS applied when 15020 port (metrics merging port) is excluded from proxy redirection (found from istio-init container).
Does that mean, we should be using the original ports and not the ports istio exposes?
PROXY_PORT=15001
PROXY_INBOUND_CAPTURE_PORT=15006
PROXY_TUNNEL_PORT=15008
PROXY_UID=1337
PROXY_GID=1337
INBOUND_INTERCEPTION_MODE=REDIRECT
INBOUND_TPROXY_MARK=1337
INBOUND_TPROXY_ROUTE_TABLE=133
INBOUND_PORTS_INCLUDE=*
INBOUND_PORTS_EXCLUDE=15090,15021,15020


From my understanding, you should be using original port exposed by application instead of sidecar one.
I am not sure this is applicable to you, but below is one of the way you can scrape where mTLS is in STRICT mode in mesh.
Again, if your organization security doesn't allow this, then don't implement it.
We kind of disabled mTLS for the Prometheus scrape port of the application by appling PeerAuthentication policy since our metrics were not returning any sensitive data.
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1
kind: PeerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: default
  namespace: foo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fluentd
  mtls:
    mode: STRICT
  portLevelMtls:
    24231:
      mode: DISABLE

24231 is the Prometheus scrape port exposed by application. Other ports of the app require mTLS but not scrape port.
https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/peer_authentication/
